# Programmatically alpha fading a premultiplied texture in OpenGL 2.0

Tags: opengl, textures, fade, alpha

I'm trying fade a premultiplied texture so it gradually becomes transparent. The problem I am having is as the alpha value goes from 1 to 0, the texture fades to black instead of being transparent.

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

// premultiply color
color.r = r * alpha;
color.g = g * alpha;
color.b = b * alpha;
color.a = alpha;
```

see image (you need a reputation of at least 10 to upload an image)

https://sites.google.com/site/soundsculptorpro/_/rsrc/1442889599502/games/blend.png



Additive blending fades out correctly but it's too bright.

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE);
// premultiply color...
```

Any ideas why additive blending would fade correctly, but alpha blending would fade to black?

**UPDATE**


fragment shader (cocos2d 2.1)...

```
"                                           \n\
#ifdef GL_ES                                \n\
precision lowp float;                       \n\
#endif                                      \n\
                                            \n\
varying vec4 v_fragmentColor;               \n\
varying vec2 v_texCoord;                    \n\
uniform sampler2D CC_Texture0;              \n\
                                            \n\
void main()                                 \n\
{                                           \n\
    gl_FragColor = v_fragmentColor * texture2D(CC_Texture0, v_texCoord); \n\
}                                           \n\
";
```

vertex shader (cocos2d 2.1)…

```
"                                                   \n\
attribute vec4 a_position;                          \n\
attribute vec2 a_texCoord;                          \n\
attribute vec4 a_color;                             \n\
                                                    \n\
#ifdef GL_ES                                        \n\
varying lowp vec4 v_fragmentColor;                  \n\
varying mediump vec2 v_texCoord;                    \n\
#else                                               \n\
varying vec4 v_fragmentColor;                       \n\
varying vec2 v_texCoord;                            \n\
#endif                                              \n\
                                                    \n\
void main()                                         \n\
{                                                   \n\
    gl_Position = CC_MVPMatrix * a_position;        \n\
    v_fragmentColor = a_color;                      \n\
    v_texCoord = a_texCoord;                        \n\
}                                                   \n\
";
```

```
_ccV3F_C4F_T2F vertices[4];

glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Position, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(_ccV3F_C4F_T2F), &vertices[0].vertices);
glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Color, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(_ccV3F_C4F_T2F), &vertices[0].colors);
glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_TexCoords, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(_ccV3F_C4F_T2F), &vertices[0].texCoords);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

Comment: I would suspect that the value you're assigning to color.a is somehow not ending up as part of the output of the fragment shader. 

How does color get fed into the graphics pipeline and what do your vertex and fragment shaders look like?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Columbo, it was color.a!  There was a bug in a utility function that was always setting color.a to 1.